# Find and Replace part of string in on a table column on first occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, wildcard

I need to find and replace all 'x' in my table with ' X ' but only on certain occasions, that is when x is near a [0-9].

This is the code I have so far, but when I execute it it replaces all occurrences

```
update  [tCustItems]
set     [CustLongDesc] = replace([CustLongDesc], 'x', ' X ')
WHERE   CustLongDesc LIKE '%[0-9]x%'

This is the result I get... 
1/2-13 X 2.75 HE X TAP BOLT FULL THRD GR5 ZINC
this is what I want...
1/2-13 X 2.75 HEX TAP BOLT FULL THRD GR5 ZINC
```

Notice that Hex is now He X

Any Ideas?

Comment: Regex and clr.  Possibly with PATINDEX and STUFF.

Comment: I'm a SQL newby....Can you posibly show an example?

Comment: If it's a one-off exercise, I'd just manually run something simple 10 times (replace '0x' with '0 X ', '1x' with '1 X ' etc) and be done with it :)

Comment: That's how I have been doing it and I it would be a time saver if I automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Put in two spaces as one does not clearly show up.
Please don't asks for more code for the second.
You asked for an example and this is an example.

```
select stuff('1/2-13X2.75 HEX TAP BOLT FULL THRD GR5 ZINC',
              patindex('%[0-9]X%','1/2-13X2.75 HEX TAP BOLT FULL THRD GR5 ZINC') + 1,0,'  ')
```